# how to get AWS access key ID & secret access key from .pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have the .PEM file for my AWS account. How to get AWS access key ID & secret access key to login to AWS CLI?
I am trying to configure my AWS CLI in windows using the command aws configure in command line. Its asking me parameters like 
Access Key ID: 
Secret Access Key:
I am not sure how to get these !! I only have .PEM file
I also don't have access to create one under the tab My Security Credentials->Users->Security Credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact your company's IT administrator, or whomever created the instance for you. They should be able to access your credentials and send it over to you. I had the same issue because I thought my .pem file was the correct credentials, but it was not. Once you obtain the access key ID and secret access key, you can then enter it in the following fields (it may have a slightly different terminology for these prompts, but you should get the idea):

```
access key ID:
secret access key:
region code: # This could be found on your management console (e.g. us-virginia-1)
```

Clarification: The .pem file contains the RSA private key, this is NOT what you need for configuring your AWS-CLI, the correct credentials will instead be referred to as 'access key ID' and 'secret access key', respectively.

Answer (score 3):

the `.pem` file allows you to connect to an ec2 instance that you have created.

the AWS access key id and AWS secret access key are information about your account and not linked to a specific instance. They are available when you create the account and after are not revealed to you

You can read this [blog post from amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/) to get more information why and how to get a new one. I'd always recommend to create a dedicated user to be used for the CLI even if you're the only one working on the account.